# Codeigniter or_where doesn't works on the server

Tags: php, codeigniter, search, activerecord

I'm trying to make search for one of my page's. Here is my query:

```
$where = array( 'user_id !=' => $id, 'privacy' => "Public" );
$this->db->select('');
$this->db->from('table');
$this->db->where($where);
$this->db->or_where('user_id', $id);
$this->db->like('name', $text);
$this->db->or_like('address', $text);
$query = $this->db->get();
```

It works fine, but it's fine only on my local machine. When I upload it on server, this query returns all my data from the table with random order. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are both your local and server running the same codeigniter version?  Is there any errors in the logs?

Comment: what if you use order_by('id','asc') function it may help you out